# Fetch SubCollection data into Recyclerview

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve data from a Firebase sub collection in a recyclerview. I think it must be possible but what I did was not right I think

I want to recover the data from REPARS_TABLE in Recyclerview
Android  - Cloud Firestore

```
    Query query = db.collection("RESTO_TABLE").document().collection("REPARS_TABLE").orderBy("nomRepars");
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ReparsModele> OptionRepars = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ReparsModele>()
            .setQuery(query,ReparsModele.class)
            .build();
    Log.d("SHOW","SHOW QUERY"+ query);
    bureauReparsAdapter = new BureauReparsAdapter(OptionRepars);
    repaLists.setHasFixedSize(true);
    repaLists.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    repaLists.setAdapter(bureauReparsAdapter);
    bureauReparsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call out the ID of the document whose subcollection you want to you.  Right now, you're calling `document()` with no parameters, which means it's generating a random ID as part of the path.  You will need to instead pass it the ID of the document.

If you don't know the ID ahead of time, then you won't be able to do this query, or you will have to use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) and filter the documents you want from all of the subcollections named "REPARS_TABLE".

Comment: If I pass an id to document (), I will only be able to reach the data of this precise document, whereas what I want here is to recover all the items of the REPARS_TABLE sub-collections in a recyclerview so independently of the 'ID. What did you suggest to me?

Comment: I gave my suggestion to that in the second paragraph of my answer.